# add menu tiles Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, menu, xamarin.forms, menuitem

I have a left expandable menu item , I would like to add to the master page a series of tiles with those menu items , like a hyperlink to the actual menu. that looks like below 
what would it be the best approach to do this using Xamarin forms , not using renders or effects 
Thanks[image: this is what I want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are a fixed number of items you can just use a grid to lay them out.

If you don't know ahead of time how many items, or the number may vary, the FlowListView plugin is probably the best bet.

https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView